# My .com domain is expiring in a few weeks - can I transfer it instead of renewing it?

Tags: domains, domain-transfer

My `.com` domain is expiring in a few weeks. I do not want to renew with the same company. If I wait until the expiration date, can I renew with a different company? Is the domain instantly released the day of the expiration date? I do not want to risk losing the domain. I tried to transfer my domain but the company will not unlock it without a $60 fee.

Comment: Define "few".  If less than 3 weeks I wouldn't recommend to attempt the transfer. As a ballpark. It may also be good to specify current registrar and future one.

Comment: The name of this registrar should be disclosed as a public service.

Comment: Seconded. I've never heard of a registrar charging a $60 "unlock fee". Even the shadiest registrars don't do this. Name and shame.

Comment: Without full details on the domain and service, just the registrar name may lead to false conclusions. At this stage of the question it is not even clear if the domain was brought directly at a registrar or a reseller or hosting company and what this fee is about exactly. We can't even be sure if the domain is not deleted already and then the fee could be the redemption one which is totally legit (in the sense that redemption is billed by the registry). So all details are needed.

Answer (score 12):

> is the domain instantly released the day of the expiration date?

No there is a grace period, then redemption period, pending delete then the domain name is deleted and becomes available for registration again. The process could take up to 75+ days.
The problem is that there is intense 'dropcatching' activity, any domain name that is remotely interesting will be snapped by somebody else within milliseconds. And everybody can see the lists of dropping domains, so don't expect that the drop will go unnoticed.

In short: allowing your domain name to expire is very dangerous.

> I do not want to risk losing the domain.

Then do not take any chance. Do not wait until it expires to renew it.

> I tried to transfer my domain but the company will not unlock it with out a $60 fee.

I don't think a lot of registrars have such a fee. Surprisingly this is allowed by Icann, see: [#9: My registrar is charging me a fee to transfer to a new registrar. Is this allowed?](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/name-holder-faqs-2017-10-10-en)
But the fact that such a fee exists is a good reason to leave that registrar imo. I am willing to bet that the annual fees are not competitive either. So by transferring to a better registrar you may save money in the long run.

Comment: The FAQ you quote at ICANN is spectacularly unclear: "However, a transfer cannot be denied due to non-payment of this transfer fee."

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Huh? What do you perceive as unclear in there? It means exactly what it says: The registrar cannot refuse a transfer just because you haven't paid their transfer fee. The registrar can only deny a transfer for the reasons listed in #8, and this is not one of them. So they cannot deny the transfer, but that doesn't mean you don't owe them the fee anymore. They're still perfectly entitled to make you pay your debt using any means necessary, but holding your domain hostage is not one of them.

Comment: "What do you perceive as unclear in there? " Saying: the registrar can have a fee but you can not pay it does not seem to me clear. Otherwise the OP wouldn't have had the question. If you refuse to pay it, obviously the registrar refuses the transfer. But it is said it can't refuse the transfer. Once the domain is transfered they have no real way to make you pay anything. As I commented below the policy is at https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/transfer-policy-2016-06-01-en and sections 3.7 3.8 3.9 explains what registrars can and can not do.

Comment: "The problem is that there is intense 'dropcatching' activity," The other problem is that the domain at some point during the process may stop to resolve (registrar either changing the nameservers or putting it on `clientHold`), hence if you do business with it it will be disrupted. And as you said you have low chances to snap it again once deleted hence it is really not the good course to pursue.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek When you go to a restaurant and order dinner, you normally get the check after the meal.  There is no way they can take the meal back, but they can make you pay.  This varies between jurisdictions, but here in the US not paying is generally considered 'theft of services' and can be a crime.  In the case of a registrar they have a record of what they did and that you owe them $60 and they can try to collect through debt collectors.  If they want to go through the trouble, they can get a judgement against you and have the authorities confiscate your property to make up the debt.

Comment: "I tried to transfer my domain but the company will not unlock it with out a $60 fee. [..] I don't think a lot of registrars have such a fee." We lack details from OP but I suspect it is not a "transfer out" fee but something else.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat "There is no way they can take the meal back, but they can make you pay." They can physically stop you and call the police. Your analogy totally does not apply in the cyber world, once the domain is transferred the old company has no assets on you or yourself to put pressure on. Yes they can go to court and debt collectors. Very unrealistic though.

Answer (score 3):

> I tried to transfer my domain but the company will not unlock it with out a $60 fee.

Unfortunately, this is the problem and needs to be resolved. Why will the company not unlock it without a fee? There shouldn't be a "fee" to unlock the domain, unless maybe the contact details have recently changed (although I'm not sure that the registrar can do much about this anyway, since it is a restriction imposed by the registry/ICANN). Or it's something that has been in the registrar's T&Cs from the beginning?

The domain needs to be unlocked before it can be transferred to a different registrar. (You will also need an EPP code.) However, if you have recently changed the contact details of the registrant on the domain then you will need to wait 3 months before it can be unlocked and transferred.

> If I wait til the expiration date, can I renew with a different company?

If you wait until the expiry date then you can transfer it to a different registrar and "renew with a different company", however, you will likely experience some downtime. And you need to clarify with the current registrar that the current $60 "unlock fee" will not still be in force. But you will likely need to have already unlocked the domain and acquired an EPP code (required by the new registrar) prior to expiry.

Ordinarily, the domain should be transferred some days (preferably weeks) *before* expiry.

> is the domain instantly released the day of the expiration date?

No. With `.com` domains they go into a 42 day "grace period" after expiry, during which time they can still be renewed at no additional cost (unless the current registrar is imposing additional fees for some reason). No one else can register the domain during this period. You can also transfer the domain during this time as well. But, as mentioned above, you will likely need to have already unlocked the domain and acquired an EPP code prior to expiry.

After the "42 day grace period", it's still not "released" but there will be additional costs involved in renewing the domain (imposed by the registry/ICANN).

Comment: Just an addendum regarding `.com's`: many registrars will charge a "redemption fee" after a certain number of days past the expiration date (GoDaddy's for example is [$80 after day 19](https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-happens-when-my-domain-expires-609)). You can sometimes get that waived or reduced by contacting them, or transfer it to another registrar to avoid paying it...

Comment: Redemption fee only happen if the domain name is deleted. If it has not expired yet, there is no reason for the registrar to delete it. And if the domain is deleted it obviously can not be transfered anywhere else (until it is first redempted)

Comment: "With .com domains they go into a 42 day "grace period" after expiry" This is 45, not 42. See https://archive.icann.org/en/registrars/gtld-lifecycle.jpg. Of course this is what the registry gives the registrar and then registrars are free to decide if they give their customer 2, 5, 10, 42, or 45 days to decide, or any other value in between. Hence it won't be uniform among registrars.

Comment: "(although I'm not sure that the registrar can do much about this anyway, since it is a restriction imposed by the registry/ICANN)." For gTLD there is a specific list enforced by ICANN of reasons for a registrar to deny a transfer, and by inference any other reason is not ground for transfer rejection. See 3.7 3.8 3.9 at https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/transfer-policy-2016-06-01-en

Comment: @dan It would seem that [GoDaddy's "grace period" ends after just 12 days](https://uk.godaddy.com/legal/agreements/domain-name-registration-agreement?pageid=REG_SA) (or is that now [19 days](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/what-happens-when-my-domain-expires-609)?), so the "redemption fee" would seem to be during the "redemption period".

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks, I didn't realise this was registrar dependent. The reason I stated "42 days" was that I recently transferred an "expired" `.com` domain that was in the stated "42 day grace period" (with UK registrar "Netistrar"). (It seems GoDaddy's grace period is just 12 days, from the links above.)

Comment: @MrWhite The emails that they send out after expiration usually refer to a "grace period" up until the redemption fee kicks in. In my experience, they don't delete domains or remove them from your account for quite a while, so you can either pay the redemption fee, contact them to discuss it, or transfer it out... But registrars might differ from each other, so this is just one example from a popular one, but not necessarily the OP's.

Comment: It goes like this (see link above with the image on gTLD lifecycle), at least for gTLDs: domain reachs expiration; the counter of 45 days start at the registry level (if nothing happens during that period, the domain is then really renewed and goes on for another year), the registrar then does what he wants regarding his customer and gives him whatever delay it wants to renew it, at some point without renew it will delete the domain, after which another grace period starts for redemption, 30 days, again at the registry level, and the registrar can undo the delete until then.